# Does the split in Red Hat and SuSE tags make sense?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

There is currently [redhat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redhat) and a [rhel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhel). It looks to me like people have been using them indiscriminately. Calling the Red Hat experts: are these tags synonyms? If there's a difference, please make it clear from the tag wikis, and retag mistagged questions. (The [redhat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redhat) tag wiki says it's about the company, but the questions are about the distribution.)

There's a similar split amongst [suse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suse): there's also [opensuse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opensuse). Is there enough difference between the two to warrant two different tags? (Possibly, after all we have [centos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centos) alongside [rhel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhel).) If the two tags should be kept, would the SuSE experts in the audience please check that they are used consistently, and write a [suse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suse) tag wiki that (tries to) direct askers to the correct tag.

---

Given the response: please synonym [redhat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redhat) into [rhel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhel).

<sub>When writing tag wikis for distributions, I suggest using a similar presentation as [arch-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arch-linux), [debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debian), [ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu).</sub>

Comment: @gilles is there enough difference between `ubuntu` and `debian`? `centos` and `rhel`? actually I'm about 90% sure `redhat` and `rhel` should be synonyms. `suse` in theory could refer to pre novell ownership.

Comment: @xenoterracide: Debian/Ubuntu, absolutely. Apart from the packaging system and some of the networking setup, if you need to invoke a specific distribution, they're often different. Centos/RHEL, perhaps less, but I remember at least one question where the difference was crucial; one question alone doesn't justify a tag so I'll let the experts pipe up.

Comment: @gilles to be honest there probably is enough of a difference at some point... in some proprietary tool or something... hah... better yet... why don't we just ask on the main site.

Comment: @xenoterracide: `/suse` should perhaps be renamed `/sles`, if it's about [“Seleste Linux”](http://serverfault.com/questions/266417/how-to-install-apt-get/266420#comment-245673)?

Comment: @gilles well there's `sles`, `sled`, and `opensuse` currently. `suse` was a distro that novell bought.

Comment: @gilles do you think that `novell` should be a tag synonym of the above?

Comment: @xenoterracide: No one's tried to use it, so no.

Comment: I don't know how much is different between `sles` and `sled` but those 2 are to `opensuse` as `rhel` is to `fedora` and I suspect many people would say those are quite different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the prospective of someone who used to work at Red Hat (and familiar with how they like their branding portrayed) my answer to the [redhat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redhat) [rhel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhel) question is that, the former is and really always was, just a reference to the company name, Red Hat Linux, was always Red Hat Linux, and Red Hat Enterprise Linux, has always being Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

While technically "RHEL" isn't a good reference to Red Hat Enterprise Linux (as I recall, RHEL isn't actually trademarked by Red Hat, which is why it is never used formally - this may have changed though), red-hat-enterprise-linux is too long of a tag, so I think [rhel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhel) is fine to use on Unix & Linux as a reference to Versions 2.1, 3, 4, 5 & 6.

I don't see much point for [redhat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redhat) as a result, I don't even think it should be a synonym for [rhel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhel) really, it'd be better (and I'm not sure if this solution exists on Stack Exchange) if the use of the tag would prompt something to the effect of: "This tag is vague, please choose out of [rhel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhel) [redhat-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redhat-linux) (for pre-RHEL releases) or ...".

[centos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centos) should remain as is, there is enough real separation from the two projects that the tags should be different.  `yum update` issues etc, will have completely different causes due to different update mechanisms (RHN, yum repository etc).

As for [suse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suse) while I'm not an expert on the SuSE Linux/OpenSuSE/Novell branding side of things, my understanding is Novell's enterprise, flagship product, is "SuSE Linux Enterprise" I think it's fair to either continue using [suse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suse), and keep the [opensuse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opensuse) tag as is, as well.  It would just be a case of checking to make sure people don't use the SuSE tag where the OpenSuSE tag is more appropriate/correct.

Comment: `redhat` is what a lot of people use to refer to RHEL (I don't think anyone's ever asked about pre-RHEL). So it should be kept. From your answer, I think a synonym is the way to go.